# Use Chain rule rigorously with correct notation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, chain-rule

In Kolk's [Multidimensional Real Analysis I: Differentiation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521551145)

He gave the Chain rule as follows:

[image]

Then he proved the following example:

[image]

What confused me is the second equality in the above Example 2.4.5, which is underlined by a yellow line. What exactly is this?

Here is my understanding: I understand that it is a "compact" style of writing a function. I mean, for example, given **any** point $a$ in $\mathbf{R}$. The author tries to convey that (using the chain rule)$D(g \circ f)(a)= (D_1g(f(a)), \cdots, D_ng(f(a)) \circ \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    Df_1(a) \\  \vdots \\ Df_n(a)
  \end{matrix}
\right)$. Then we can use **legitimate matrix multiplication** to get the final result.

I think it's not rigorous:

1. He writes $(Dg\circ f)$ as $((D_1g,\cdots,D_ng)\circ f)$. However, each $D_ig$ is a **function** from $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}$ and he just wrote them in a row vector, pretending they have accepted $f$'s output as input and have output a scalar in $\mathbf{R}$. I've never seen expressions like this before. Besides, how to prove $Dg=(D_1g,\cdots,D_ng)$? Is the total derivative equal to some **undefined list** of partial derivatives?
2. The same expression appeared in $\left(
     \begin{matrix}
       Df_1 \\  \vdots \\ Df_n
     \end{matrix}
   \right)$
3. I think if someone doesn't know **in advance** what the author tries to convey. These are all invalid expressions. So how should a beginner like me use these expressions correctly to prove more complicated statements?

Comment: @Troposphere Yes, you are right. But I am emphasizing $(Dg) \circ f$, not $D(g \circ f)$, I mean  $D(g \circ f) = ((Dg) \circ f) \circ Df$, see theorem 2.4.1

Comment: Sorry, I misread the actual quote in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author implicitly identified derivative at a point $a$ as its matrix representation.

In fact, in example 2.4.5, the author emphasized this identification:

> the derivative $D(g \circ f): \mathbf{R} \rightarrow End(\mathbf{R}) \simeq \mathbf{R} $

So if it was me, I would write the equation in Example 2.4.5 as follows:

for any $a \in \mathbf{R}$,

\begin{align}
[D(g \circ f)(a)]_{1 \times 1} &= [Dg(f(a))]_{1 \times n} \circ [Df(a)]_{n \times 1}\tag{Jacobi matrix notation} \\
&=[D_1g(f(a)), \cdots, D_ng(f(a))]_{1 \times n} \circ   \left( \begin{matrix}
    Df_1(a) \\  \vdots \\ Df_n(a)
  \end{matrix} \right)_{n \times 1} \\
&= \sum_{1\leq i\leq n} (D_ig(f(a))) \cdot Df_i(a)
\end{align}

I don't think the "compact style" of writing an equation is good for learning.